# SteamCMD alternative for ARM CPU

Tags: linux, arm, steam

I've got an OCI free tier 4 Core 24 GB ram instance. I ran modded minecraft server and it is very smooth. I want to go one step ahead and create server for any valve game such like GMod or CS:GO. As far as I know SteamCMD can be run only on amd or intel cpus. So is there any alternative for ARM architecures cpus? I know I can virtualise it with QEMU but it's hard and it also kills efficiency.